# Can you add icon into input field without using CSS?

Tags: html

I'm practicing making a simple modal login form using HTML and Bootstrap 4. I'm planning to put icons into my email and password field to make it looks interesting. However it looks like most of the method to do this are by using css to add the icons into input fields. I was wondering, can you add icons into input fields without using css?

Comment: you can't - you have to use some css, inputs won't take html elements so you can't use an svg or img in them

Answer (score 0):

You can add source into your head with icons and then use them with  class.

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>

<i class="fas fa-cloud"></i>
<i class="fas fa-heart"></i>
<i class="fas fa-car"></i>
<i class="fas fa-file"></i>
<i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
```

to make it looks like it's inside the input field, you need use some css. It can be inside your lines:

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
<body>

<div id="yourDiv" style="border:1px solid black; width:200px">
  <i class="fas fa-heart"></i>
  <input style=border:0px>
</div>


</body>
```

Comment: Now I get it. It works now, thanks for the suggestion